# Discord.py how to pass ctx as a default argument

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm writing a profile command using Discord.py which prints out information about the specified user.

I would like to pass the message author as the default argument, so if the user just writes the command and nothing else, the bot will send their profile.

```
@bot.command()
async def profile(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = ctx.message.author):
```

The above code doesn't work.
It errors out with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 50, in <module>
    async def profile(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = ctx.message.author.name):
NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and how to make my code work?

**EDIT:**

I sort of bypassed the problem with:

```
@bot.command()
async def profile(ctx, *, user: discord.Member=None):
        if(user == None):
                user = ctx.message.author
```

My question still remains, is there any way to pass ctx as a default argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do that, as you would be altering the signature of the function. Commands are called expecting this signature:

```
async def my_command(ctx, *args, **kwargs):
```

`ctx` is not a given value, just the name of the first parameter. You can't make assumptions about what is going to be used for.

What you can do, is assume the number of parameters, following the example that's in the discord.py documentation, you can do something like this:

```
async def profile(ctx, *, user:discord.Member):
    member = user or ctx.message.author
```

In this code, you can assume `member` is always a Member, except in a private channel, when it would be a User.

Comment: Yeah, I sort of assumed ctx can't be passed, but couldn't figure out why based on the documentation, thank you for the explanation and the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

you can use this -

```
user = ctx.author if not user else user
```

instead of -

```
if(user == None):
                user = ctx.message.author
```

Comment: No problem :) can you also [accept this as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ? Thanks!